# conda create -n test pandas=0.12.0 (?)

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, conda

I am trying to make a separate conda environment using conda create to allow old scripts to run with pandas version 0.12.0

Using `conda create -n test pandas=0.12.0`

I have updated to the latest conda using:
`conda update conda` which is 3.0.3

I get the following error:

```
Error: Unsatisfiable package specifications
Hint: pandas 0.12|0.12.0* has a conflict with the remaining packages
```

Where am I going wrong? [Do I need to specify a numpy and python version? np17py27]

Comment: try setting the version of anaconda where pandas0.12.0 was distributed. 1.8 i'm guessing since they just pushed 1.9

Comment: Ahh - that works - thanks! ... conda create -n test pandas=0.12.0 anaconda=1.8

Comment: I just came across this same error, confusing.

Comment: I have written to Anaconda Support and their response: "This is an issue that we're working on. The workaround right now is to also specify scipy=0.13.2." Specifying anaconda=1.8 works but brings in a lot of packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Temporary Fix**

This is the suggestion from Anaconda Support.

```
conda create -n <your_env_name> pandas=0.12.0 scipy=0.13.2
```

This brings in the following packages:

[image: Pandas, Scipy]

**Note**: If you want to use IPython that will also need to be specified as this will create an environment with python2.7. Without specifying IPython then IPython is linked with Pandas 0.13.0

Comment: The issue is if you don't specify IPython then it pulls the one from the root environment, which has the newer pandas.